# drupal 7 Control form #states visible, also hide the title

Tags: drupal, states, form-api

I have two form fields and one of them is dependent on other i.e., if coupon value is 'Yes', show the coupon_code textbox

```
$form['coupon'] = array(
    '#id' => 'coupon',
    '#key_type' => 'associative',
    '#multiple_toggle' => '1',
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array(
            '' => 'Select',
            'Yes' => 'Yes',
            'No' => 'No'
            ),
    '#default_value' => '',
    '#required' => TRUE
);

$form['coupon_code'] = array(
    '#id' => 'coupon_code',
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => $couponCode,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#states' => array(
        'visible' => array(// action to take.
            ':input[name="coupon"]' => array('value' => 'Yes'),
        ),
    ),
);
```

and in my tpl file

```
<tr>
 <td class='formlabel' valign=middle>Coupon</td>
            <td align=left>
                <?php echo render($form['coupon']); ?>
                <font class='redmark'>*</font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='formlabel' valign=middle>Coupon Code</td>
            <td align=left>
                <?php echo render($form['coupon_code']); ?>
                <font class='redmark'>*</font>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

The coupon_code is not visible when coupon value is 'No', but I also want to hide label "Coupon Code", how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add the '#title' attribute to the form array. This will be output as the label, if the field is visible. You would also have to change the tpl file to remove the label you entered manually.

```
$form['coupon'] = array(
    '#id' => 'coupon',
    '#key_type' => 'associative',
    '#multiple_toggle' => '1',
    '#title' => 'Coupon',
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array(
            '' => 'Select',
            'Yes' => 'Yes',
            'No' => 'No'
            ),
    '#default_value' => '',
    '#required' => TRUE
);

$form['coupon_code'] = array(
    '#id' => 'coupon_code',
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => $couponCode,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#title' => 'Coupon Code',
    '#states' => array(
        'visible' => array(// action to take.
            ':input[name="coupon"]' => array('value' => 'Yes'),
        ),
    ),
);
```

This is probably the best approach IMHO, if you don't want to do this, you could also add a JavaScript event trigger to the coupon select, that will show/hide the label.